# Save ZIP file from REST web service using Postman tool

Tags: rest, jackson, postman

I have created a web service to send a ZIP file as output. I use POST method in the request (send file as input).

How do I download a file in the Postman tool?

I get the response like this (content of ZIP file in text):

> `PK`

I need the file to be saved.

Answer (score 44):

Postman provide **Send and Download** option .

Select the Send and Download from dropdown .It will download and save the response in a file.
[image]

Answer (score 16):

You can use the `Send and Download` option in order to download the file, though, you will get a dialogue asking where to save the file.